# Событие по клику на ячейке таблицы(JAVA)

Tags: gui, java

Ребята, подскажите, пожалуйста как сделать так, чтобы по клику левой кнопкой мыши по ячейке таблицы она заполнялась нужным мне символом, по повторному клику очищалась. А по клику правой кнопки там же появлялся другой символ.
Спасибо =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача не тривиальная, потому смогу подсказать, только направление в этом вопросе =)

1. Надо реализовать свою модель, имплементируя интерфейс (`implements TableModel` )
2. Повесить на таблицу маус-листенер
3. Проверять нажатие клавиши
4. Брать номер ячейки
5. И выводить нужную информацию